# Need a Solution for getting the website to work on disabling of javascript in the browser

Tags: javascript, noscript

I have a website which uses a lot of javascript. My problem is on disabling the javascript option in the browser the website will not function as desired.

Two solutions I found were:

1. I added this tag in the header of the page:

   ```
   <noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=/noscript.php" />
   ```

   On load the page gets redirected to the new page. But on doing some research. I found on stackoverflow that it has issues with seo as the crawlers will index the noscript page and thereby affect the seo of website.
2. Just display a message like stackoverflow does when javascript is disabled inside noscript tag. I think they have also created separate form which use server side validation when this happens.

Besides redoing the functionality for server side validation on all forms. Is there any other solution which I can make use of. Also I would like to know if the solution 1 is not a good option. As I have seen facebook is also making use of it.

Thanks in Advance.

I have found this to work the way I want. Would like to know, what you'll think about it?

```
<noscript>
 <font face=arial>JavaScript must be enabled in order for you to use the site.</font>      <style type="text/css">
#wrapper { display: none; }
</style>  
</noscript>
```

Comment: _"Besides redoing the functionality for server side validation on all forms"_ - You should be doing server-side validation anyway, to allow for malicious users bypassing your client-side validation.

Comment: @ swati: Cannot emphasize nnnnnn's point enough: You can't trust **anything** the client sends you. Server-side validation is not optional, no matter what you're doing on the client.

Comment: No other way...you expect user enables javascript in his browser to run the code..

Comment: Thanks for the response. There are a few areas where I need certain js libraries to be used on certain forms. So that is the main reason I wanted js enabled.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you should always be validating user-input on the server side as well as the client. This probably isn't the answer you want to hear (it will mean additional work at first) but if you don't then your website is open to attack.

When building a website which needs to support non-JavaScript users, I find it's a lot easier to start with a basic HTML/CSS site and layer JavaScript functionality over the top. This is called [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement).

If you don't need to (or really don't want to) support non-JavaScript users, then I'd go with option 2 – kindly prompt the user that they need to enable JavaScript to use all of the site's features.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes I get that. But if I hide the content of the site from loading then I am preventing the user from any attack isn't it?

Comment: No, because anyone with a small amount of knowledge of JavaScript can bypass your client-side validation and send malicious data to your server-side